# How to: Oracle analytic function to return row

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

I guess my question could be answered with an
Oracle analytic function in the SQL but I am not
to sure.
Say I have the following "DOCUMENTS" DB Table:

- Rank: Reverse Sequence, each document has its own sequence, **latest document revision has lowest (0) number**
- Revision: Alpha numerical sequence per document, **latest document revision  has highest revision id**

| NAME | RANK | REVISION | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DocumentA | 0 | 5b | ReadOnly |
| DocumentA | 1 | 5a | Draft |
| DocumentA | 3 | 3 | ReadOnly |
| DocumentA | 4 | 2 | Draft |
| DocumentA | 2 | 4 | Published |
| DocumentA | 5 | 1 | Published |
| DocumentB | 0 | 2 | Draft |
| DocumentB | 1 | 1 | Published |
| DocumentC | 0 | 1 | Published |

Requested result set: Latest published revision for each document

*Give me, for each document, the latest published document, having the lowest rank number*

Since the latest document revision can be in state draft it is not always 0

| NAME | RANK | REVISION | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DocumentA | 2 | 4 | Published |
| DocumentB | 1 | 1 | Published |
| DocumentC | 0 | 1 | Published |

Please formulate the SQL query to return this result set. Many thanks!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group

Comment: Do you want to get the penultimate rows just before `Draft` whenever descendingly ordered starting from the earliest ones?

Comment: I am interested only in published revisions, no matter how many document revisions have been added before or later

Comment: You decide for DocumentA RANK 2 REVISION 4, because RANK 2 < RANK 5 or because REVISION 4 > REVISION 1?

Comment: Because rank 2 < rank 5. I want the published revisions having the lowest rank, since that is the newest document revision.

Comment: So, we can ignore the revision column completely? This would have been easier to understand, had you just omitted it from your request :-) Littlefoot's answer should work for you. Only remove the revision from the order by clause.

Comment: Correct. The revision is not necessary for the query. I added it only to better visualise the reverse character of the rank.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with test (name, rank, revision, state) as
  2    (select 'A', 0, '5b', 'ReadOnly'  from dual union all
  3     select 'A', 2,  '4', 'Published' from dual union all
  4     select 'A', 5,  '1', 'Published' from dual union all
  5     select 'B', 0,  '2', 'Draft'     from dual union all
  6     select 'B', 1,  '1', 'Published' from dual union all
  7     select 'C', 0,  '1', 'Published' from dual
  8     )
  9  select name, rank, revision, state
 10  from (select t.*,
 11          rank() over (partition by name order by revision desc, rank) rn
 12        from test t
 13        where state = 'Published'
 14       )
 15  where rn = 1;

N       RANK RE STATE
- ---------- -- ---------
A          2 4  Published
B          1 1  Published
C          0 1  Published

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Requested result set: Latest published revision for each document

One method doesn't use window functions:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.state = 'Published' and
      t.rank = (select min(t2.rank) 
                from t t2
                where t2.name = t.name and t2.state = t.state
               );
```

And, in Oracle, you can even use aggregation:

```
select document, state, min(rank),
       min(revision) keep (dense_rank first order by rank) as revision
from t
where state = 'Published'
group by document, state;
```

Window functions are a very reasonable solution to the problem, however, they are not required.